# How can I get the text of each link embedded in a div?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to get a list of titles in this post 
http://www.vn-meido.com/k1/index.php?topic=6646.msg38869#msg38869

and this is the code

```
from os import system
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

list_url = "http://www.vn-meido.com/k1/index.php?topic=6646.msg38869#msg38869"

list_page = requests.get(list_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(list_page.content,'html5lib')
titles = soup.find_all('div',{"class":"inner", "id":"msg_38869"})
title_list = []

for t in titles:
    title = t.find('a').text
    title_list.append(title)

print(title_list)
```

but it only get the first title in the post:

```
['10 nen goshi no HikiNiito o Yamete Gaishutsushitara Jitaku goto Isekai']
```

I know that there is something wrong with the loop but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Where the code says `soup.find_all('div',{"class":"inner", "id":"msg_38869"})` - how many such `div`s are you expecting? Where the code says `t.find('a').text` - how many such `a` tags are you expecting? According to the documentation (or for that matter, the *names*, how many things can you find with the `find` method? How many things can you find with the `find_all` method? Do you see the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get all elements and then append their text to your list.

```
from os import system
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

list_url = "http://www.vn-meido.com/k1/index.php?topic=6646.msg38869#msg38869"

list_page = requests.get(list_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(list_page.content, 'html5lib')
titles = soup.find_all('div', {"class": "inner", "id": "msg_38869"})
title_list = []

for t in titles:
    title = t.find_all('a')
    for x in title:
        title_list.append(x.text)

print(title_list)
```

Comment: There should only be one `<div class="inner" id="msg_38869">`, so it should be sufficient on the other hand to `.find` that and use it instead of iterating over a list.